# I'm model 8525-001 windows 3.1 install from MS-DOS

Tags: windows

First of all, I wanted to say that I am very new to IBM computers and DOS.

I have with me my IBM model "8525" that I picked up at an antique store for $10 yesterday evening. It runs perfectly fine. It was a little bit dusty, but what cant a little alcohol wipes fix :)

So, my questions are:

- how do I go about installing Microsoft Windows version 3.1 OR OLDER on this device? I have TONS of floppy disks that are empty laying around my basement.
- what software would I use to put said software on the PC?

Comment: As I recall Win3.1 came on 8 floppies: you insert disc 1, type `a:\setup.exe` and it will churn away and periodically ask you for the next disc. After all the discs are installed, reboot and there you have it, Win3.1 in all its glory. When the TV programme `24` was doing the rounds, College Humor ran an amusing spoof, setting the action before mobile 'phones, in the days of Windows 3.1. It doesn't seem to be on their [web-site](http://www.collegehumor.com/) now, but I found it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMLH_QyPTYM). Still worth a watch.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty basic stuff and you haven't listed anything wrong or broken that needs fixing or solving.

Comment: @AFH Close. 3.1 was 6 floppies. The Workgroups edition was 8. :)

Comment: @PatrickSeymour - That's probably what I was using (I only ever used it at work), or else I was including the two DOS installation discs.

Comment: I have found a set of seven disks on ebay that look like they'll get the job done. Can anybody tell me if these would work on my machine? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Microsoft-Windows-Operating-System-Version-3-11-set-of-7-3-5-Diskettes/161476417121?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D51376%26meid%3D1c533d40bab2409b91a3475391653e04%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D161476417121%26itm%3D161476417121&_trksid=p2481888.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Abbedf065-41bc-11e8-8c25-74dbd180dc73%7Cparentrq%3Ad05981da1620a88459682649fffff138%7Ciid%3A1#rwid&autorefresh=true

Comment: @PatrickSeymour - I've just found my Win3.1 floppy images among my archives, and there are 8 of them: `DISK1\SETUP.INF` in the `[dialog]` section contains `title     = "Installing Windows for Workgroups 3.11". So we're both right. I'm not sure I was even aware of the other edition - I certainly never used it. Did it miss out networking support or some such?

Comment: I’m not sure how we’re both right; I said Workgroups was 8. But yes, I think the last two disks were the network crap.

Comment: @OzzyFilms - You should probably seek out the Workgroups edition.

Comment: @PatrickSeymour - I correctly remembered 8 discs, and you correctly remembered that they were the Workgroups edition.

Comment: Disk images for these versions can be found at WinWorldPC. A more suitable discussion site might be Retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 3.1 requires a minimum of an 80286 processor, and requires a '386 for some features.

The information I'm seeing online appears to indicate that the IBM 8285-001 was an 8086 system, and hence wouldn't be able to run Windows 3.1.

Comment: Windows 3.0 might work though -https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.0